# How to export email from Sugar CRM

Tags: sugarcrm, dynamics-crm-2013

Requirement is to Import All Contact, Account and it's related activities to export from Sugar CRM.
And after export data from Sugar CRM, these files will imported to CRM.
How we can import Email from Sugar CRM without database access?

Thanks
Anand

Comment: the target system is dynamics crm? which version?

Comment: target system is MS Dynamic CRM 2013.

Comment: Target system is MS Dynamic CRM 2013.